# Prove that for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(2nx)dx=0$ if $f(x)$ is odd.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-verification

If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R  $ is odd continuous function such that  $g(x):=f(x + \frac{\pi}{2})$ is even, prove that for every $n 
\in \mathbb N$, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(2nx)dx=0$.

Since $f(x)$ is odd and $\sin(2nx)$ is odd, product of two odd functions is even, it follows that $f(x)\sin(2nx)$ is even, hence $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(2nx)dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(2nx)dx$. Now, let $x=t+\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then we have  $2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(2nx)dx=2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(t+\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(2n(t+\frac{\pi}{2}))dt=2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}g(t)\sin(2n(t+\frac{\pi}{2}))dt$. Since we have that $g(t)$ is even and $\sin(2n(t+\frac{\pi}{2}))$ is odd, we have that their product is odd hence  $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}g(t)\sin(2n(t+\frac{\pi}{2}))dt=0$ i.e. $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(2nx)dx= \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}g(t)\sin(2n(t+\frac{\pi}{2}))dt=0$

Comment: Is there a question here? It seems you answered it yourself

Comment: @OfekGillon Well it was tagged proof verification.

Comment: Right, didn't notice that. I think the proof is good but if it is part of a work you should explain why $\sin(2n(t+\frac{\pi}{2}))$ is odd (the argument that $\sin t$ is odd isn't enough because the addition of $\frac{\pi}{2}$